# Can't remember details or name of a story about humans enslaved by cats

Tags: story-identification

I read a book aeons ago. Barely remember details except humans were slaves to cats. The book suggests that the cats had rebelled against humans and overthrew them

Comment: Please *try* to remember more details. And "aeons" was like, what, 60 years ago?

Comment: You're describing my life.

Comment: Can you add anything else from [this list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)? Also, care to take a look if current answer suits you?

Comment: Humans enslaved by Cats: https://archive.org/details/TheAmazingAlexandersnlSpoof

Comment: "a story about humans enslaved by cats" That's called real life, friend.

Answer (score 5):

Might not be what you are after, but The Sandman comic "Dream of a Thousand Cats" kind of fits your description. It was reprinted in the "Dream Country" trade paperback.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Dream_Country#A_Dream_of_a_Thousand_Cats

Comment: You should probably state that in this one it was the humanity who overthrew the cats. _Then_ the cats started planning to overthrow humans.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this book while looking for something else.  I have not read it, but it seems to match the details in the question:

[*Godsfire*, by Cynthia Felice* (1978)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/967895.Godsfire)

The plot summary, per the above GoodReads link:

> Heao is a member of Academe, a future group of intelligentsia on a planet in the throes of a receding ice age. She and all her people have been conquered by a primitive king whose dreams of destruction haunt him, and may doom all her kind. Heao is intelligent and loving, a devoted helpmate and mother. But Heao is not an ordinary woman. She is a member of a feline race, and her body, along with those of her peers, is covered with fur and ends in a long busy tail. She is a member of the master race of Shadowland, the race that keeps human slaves to do their work for them, the race that stands in powerless awe of the fiery ball of light she sees once a year—Godsfire!
>
> In Heao’s world she is a pathfinder, a mapmaker, and she is the Galileo of her world, determined to bring light and wisdom to her shadowed world where most folk see slaves not as merely different but inferior. Heao knows better and won’t deny her belief that slaves are intelligent and if not human, certainly more than animals. Her temple adversary, Tarana, would subdue and control, the young pathfinder to steal her dream-goal, or kill her if that fails. The king-conqueror, with tortured dreams of his own, needs Heao’s mapmaking skills as much as he needs the Temple’s support. Even Heao helper-in-life, Baltsar, and her trusted slave, Teon, are affected by the unintended consequences of Heao’s convictions and her quest to follow her dream-goal. It will take all of them through the Evernight Mountains to discover the truth about her world and the blinding vision of—Godsfire!

[image: Godsfire cover]

*What great name for somebody writing about anthropomorphic cats!

Comment: That tail is positively *naughty*.